# How to improve humidity immunity of a self-capacitive touch sensor?

Tags: capacitive-sensor, stm32l4+

I am using the internal TSC module of STM32L4+ MCUs, but it only supports self-capacitive touch sensors. I know that these types of sensors can face issues with moisture and water. Is it possible to enhance the water and humidity immunity of such sensors through any hardware or software design techniques?